# Error while using Selenium: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: python, selenium, roblox

I've been looking at other questions that were the exact same, and nothing solved my issue. I'm trying to use Selenium with Python to interact with Roblox. However, every time I try to run my code, it give me an error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Users\popsi\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I'm not sure has caused this, as I have compatible versions of Selenium, Chrome, and Chromedriver. I've tried adding arguments, changing things around, and some other things, but to no avail.